# Поиск разницы между элементами большого списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Коллеги, прошу совета. Дан список из `float`. Список может быть большой - миллионы элементов. Мы берем каждый элемент списка и проверяем каждый следующий элемент на разницу между ними. Как только абсолютное значение разницы равно или превышает заранее заданную величину мы заводим флаг в специально подготовленный список, который показывает - получили мы положительную или отрицательную разницу либо мы достигли конца списка, но условия не достигли.

Очевидное, но "тупое" решение данной задачи:

```
float_list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 3.0, 1.0]
flag_list = []
lim = 2 # значение 0 невозможно
for i in range(len(float_list)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(float_list)):
        if abs(float_list[j]-float_list[i]) >= lim:
            if float_list[j]-float_list[i] > 0:
                flag_list.append(1)
            else:
                flag_list.append(-1)
            break
    else:
        flag_list.append(0)
flag_list.append(0) # для последнего элемента условие никогда не выполнится
print(float_list)
print(flag_list)
```

Также я пытался применить `map`, также пытался конвертировать в `pandas.Series` и применять `apply`. Все это - очень долго.

Отсюда вопрос - возможно, вы подскажете какое-то изящное решение, которое от меня ускользает, чтобы эта задача не превращалась в тупой перебор. Особенно, учитывая, что условие может не выполнится, а это значит, что мы вынуждены будем перелопачивать весь список до конца.

**UPD.**
Из комментариев стало понятно, что есть ряд неясных моментов.
Проясняю:

1. Все входные данные положительные
2. Входные данные хаотичны и могут повторяться
3. Последовательность данных важна
4. Конечной целью задачи является - присвоить каждому из элементов списка флаг с соответствующим знаком - нашли мы ПОСЛЕ текущего элемента, другой элемент, который отличается на lim в большую или меньшую сторону.
5. **Важно какая разница встретилась первой - положительная или отрицательная** - в зависимости от знака первой разницы, соответствующей условию, мы выставляем положительный или отрицательный флаг.

Благодарю!

Comment: не изобретайте велосипед, воспользуйтесь модулем pandas

Comment: А какой итог должен быть? Вопрос задачи какой? "Найти все разницы между всеми элементами" или "найти хотя бы 1 пару элементов, разница  между которыми превышает lim"?

Comment: Если список отсортировать, избавимся от квадратичного поведения.Не исключено, что можно сделать и линейный алгоритм, но нужно больше подробностей о задаче.

Comment: @MBo Да может вообще имеет смысл сразу минимум и максимум на интересующем отрезке брать и по ним сравнивать. Но нужно проверять - будет ли это быстрее. Библиотеки типа numpy должны такое быстро делать. Вообще данные бы посмотреть, как они распределены и всё такое. Может там выгоднее с конца списка идти, например )

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, но тут могут быть детали - например, важно ли, что отрицательная разница встретилась раньше положительной и т.п.

Comment: @MBo А, ну да, знак же. Тогда без перебора вряд ли.

Comment: На сортированном массиве можно текущий элемент сравнивать только с последним элементом - получится линейная сложность.

Comment: Что-то я уже сомневаюсь, что тут можно что-то придумать алгоритмически. Максимум `numba.njit` попробовать накатить.

Comment: Коллеги, большое спасибо за участие! Постараюсь ответить сразу на все вопросы, которые вы задали. 1. Все входные данные положительные 2. Входные данные хаотичны. 3. Последовательность данных важна 3. Конечной целью задачи является ровно то, что описано в задаче - присвоить каждому из элементов списка флаг - нашли мы ПОСЛЕ текущего элемента, другой элемент, который отличается на lim в большую или меньшую сторону 4. Знак разницы важен. 5. Не важно положительная или отрицательная разница встретилась первой - важна только первая "встреча".

Comment: А числа все уникальные и точность чисел важна абсолютная? А то у меня бредовая мысль идти с конца списка, заносить все значения в сортированный список или словарь и чтобы индексы ближайших встреченных элементов там были. Только мысль про сортировку или сразу поиск я не додумал.

Comment: Хотя нет, на рандоме вообще список из 100 млн. элементов весь уникальный получился. Это тогда сводится к сортированному списку задача как у MBo

Comment: *nlogn* с помощью k-2 tree и несколько модифицированным поиском.

Comment: @CrazyElf Внес апдейт в вопрос - там разъяснения.  Значения на входе могут повторятся. А могут и нет.

Comment: Блин, вроде придумал метод, но он тоже неправильный. Наверное, без дерева и его полного обхода тут никак вообще, печалька.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проходим от начала и рассматриваем каждый элемент по очереди.

Далее описаны действия для каждого элемента `E[i]`:

1. добавляем элемент `E[i]` вместе с его индексом в дерево, которое хранит уже просмотренные элементы, для которых еще не найдены совпадения.
2. Находим в дереве все элементы, которые отстоят от текущего на `eps` или больше. Для каждого такого элемента `E[j]` в зависимости от того, в какую сторону он отстоит от текущего `E[i]`, записываем результат и удаляем элемент `E[j]` из дерева.

Т.е. тут поиск идет не от элемента вперед по списку, а от элемента назад, и среди уже просмотренных элементов ищем есть ли такие, для которых текущий подходит по условию достаточной разности.

Итого каждый элемент добавим и удалим максимум один раз - сложность `O(n*log(n))`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

l = [1, 2, 3, -2, 3, 0]
e = 2

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ElementWithIndex:
    value: int
    index: int

unmatched = SortedList(key=lambda el: el.value)

f = [0] * len(l)

for i in range(len(l)):
    el = l[i]
    while unmatched and unmatched[0].value <= el - e:
        f[unmatched[0].index] = 1
        unmatched.pop(0)
    while unmatched and unmatched[-1].value >= el + e:
        f[unmatched[-1].index] = -1
        unmatched.pop(-1)

    unmatched.add(ElementWithIndex(value=el, index=i))

print(f"l={l}")
print(f"e={e}")
print(f"f={f}")
```

Comment: А дерево как ветвится то - больше-меньше следующий элемент?

Comment: Годится любая структура данных, которая поддерживает отсортированность при вставке/удалении и дает вставку/удаление/поиск за log(n). В питоне нет встроенной, к сожалению, https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html сгодится

Comment: Требуются пояснения. Из Вашего алгоритма мне кажется, что он ищет не каждое следующее от текущего элемента совпадение с условием, а просто все подряд совпадения с условием. Я не верно понимаю?

Comment: Нет, алгоритм ищет именно следуюющее совпадение, как в условии задачи. Только он делает это в другую сторону, т.е. с точки зрения элемента который правее в списке. Я расширил описание алгоритма, надеюсь так понятней. Я не уверен, что понимаю вопрос. Что значит "каждое следующее совпадение"? Тут вопрос в том найдет ли он ближайший элемент, у которого разность достаточная? Если так, то да, т.к. алгоритм идет слева направо и ищет разность с элементами левее текущего.

Comment: Спасибо! Разберусь!

Comment: Вроде понятно! А если мы не "дерево" будем использовать (для меня это неизвестное пока знание), а будем список использовать (только, на сколько я понял, все равно придется где-то индексы хранить, то есть придется превратить список флоатов в словарь, например), то мы все равно выиграем же, по сравнению с вложенным перебором, который у меня в вопросе?

Comment: Обычный список (он же массив) не годится, так как в нем поиск, добавление и удаление не за логарифмическое время (а за линейное и это делает алгоритм O(n*n) как у вас вопросе описано). Нужна именно структура, которая позволяет делать это за log(n). Выше я дал ссылку на SortedList, с ним просто работать.

Comment: ОК, ясно, благодарю!

Comment: Вижу апдейт с кодом! Погонял на синтетических данных - работает! Проверю на живых данных - вернусь с докладом о снижении времени обработки :) Спасибо!

Comment: Неожиданное и красивое решение. Браво!